CUDA 12.5 with Visual Studio 2022 v17.10.3 not working
I am using Visual Studio Community 2022 with CUDA toolkit. However, once I upgraded to v17.10.3 the CUDA toolikt crashes with "'cudafe++' died with status 0xC0000409" and "nvcc.exe exited with code 9" error. This happens with CUDA 12.4 and the latest CUDA 12.5.
I tried to roll back Visual Studio, but I can only roll back to v17.10.2 which has the same problem. It used to work with Visual Studio 17.9 but I don't seem to be able to roll back to that version. Any ideas how to roll back Visual Studio 2022 Community to v17.9 or make CUDA toolkit work with v17.10?

Related: cudafe++ died with status 0xc0000409 when switching to c++20 for nvcc

Yes, thank you. Using --std c++17 for nvcc rather than inheriting --std c++20 does fix this issue for me. I get a few warnings as I am using c++20 for the rest of the code but it works fine.

It was not confirmed that this bug was actually reported to Nvidia, so maybe you should report it just in case.
